# Corrupted World Round

Tags: terraria

I am in pre-hardmode and I've heard that the hallow and corruption will consume a V-shaped part of the world. Any tips on how to stop this before hardmode starts and without using blocks at all.

Comment: Also can anyone tell me how to stop corrupted thorny bushes from growing

Comment: Oh Srry I didn't see that